# Jquery Hover display

Tags: jquery

I am trying to have a simple button that when hovered over it shows my div. My first attempt was something like this:

```
$('.headerUserPreferences a').hover(function() {
    $('.headerUserPreferencesLinks').stop().toggle();
}, function() {
    $('.headerUserPreferencesLinks').mouseOut(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

but the problem here is that you have to hover over the button again to make the div hide. How can I do it where as long as you are hovering over the button or the div the div will show and when you go off the div or the button the div will not display anymore.

Comment: Why not, just this : $('.headerUserPreferences a').hover(function() {
    $('.headerUserPreferencesLinks').show();
}, function() {
    $('.headerUserPreferencesLinks').hide();
});

Comment: Vote to @TJ-
hover function is possible to have 2 parameters. First is mouse in event handler and second is mouse out event handler.
So, no need `mouseOut` function any more

Comment: TJ I tried the code but when I hover over headerUserPreferencesLinks it disappears. I need it to stay for as long as they are hoving over headerUserPreferencesLinks or the headerUserPreferences  a

Comment: Check this. Sample on jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/g2msn/1/ .This one is only for hovering over headerUserPreferences. Can you show your html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.headerUserPreferences a').hover(function() { 
    $('.headerUserPreferencesLinks').toggle(); 
});

$('.headerUserPreferencesLinks').mouseout(function() { 
        $(this).hide(); 
}); 

$('.headerUserPreferencesLinks').mouseover(function() { 
        $(this).show(); 
});
```

Comment: This works but when I hover over headerUserPreferencesLinks it disappears. I need to stay if I am hover over the button or headerUserPreferencesLinks

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer to use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`

```
$("div.enterleave").mouseenter(function(){
     // code div display
    }).mouseleave(function(){
     // code div hide
    });
```

hope this example would help..

for more refer http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.headerUserPreferences a').mouseover(function() {
    $('.headerUserPreferencesLinks').stop().toggle();
}, function() {
    $('.headerUserPreferencesLinks').mouseout(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```